# Componets tab in react dev tools is not working properly

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I have just installed the React Dev Tools extension in google chrome.
I realized that the React tab in the inspect bar was replaced by Components and Profiler tabs.

But for some reason, The rendered tree is not complete in the components tab
take a look at the following pictures

This is what my app looks like in the Components tab

[image]

This is what I am expecting it to look like

[image]

And I don't know why it is showing Anonymous key = 'something' ForwardRef... Instread of showing a component over there

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

As mentioned I have installed the styled-components plugin
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2vnd.png

Comment: I am curious how you are exporting your components? are you doing it like this `export default (props) =>...`

Comment: No, I do it like export default <component-name>

Comment: If you are using `forwardRef` you need to set `displayName` otherwise it not show the ComponentName, erm that's just how hoc works as of moment. Not a fan of `displayName` but whatever works xD

Comment: Hey just a thought, are you perhaps using styled component?

Comment: If so have you installed the `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components`

Comment: Yeah, I use styled-components. and I have installed the above plugin. no work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are following these:

- if you are using default export of components, there is no name for the component for dev tools to use.

try:

```
const HelloWorld = () => {
  return <h1>Hello</h1>;
};

export default HelloWorld; // Now tool has a name to work on.
```

- For HoC, you can use 'displayName' property:

More useful ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#displaying-a-custom-name-in-devtools

- React dev tools allows you to see the components that are in 'DEV' mode and not running production build.

Update after checking code:

- You are using higher order components and as I mentioned earlier/above HoC needs explicit `displayName`

  ```
   const PersonWithRadium = Radium(Person);
   PersonWithRadium.displayName = "PersonWithRadium";
   export default PersonWithRadium;
  ```

[image: Dev tools snippet]

Comment: Yes I have done exactly as you mentioned yet I don't get the display name

Comment: And why I am I seeing that awkward tree structure and not like in the recond image?

Comment: you use yarn/npm start right? how do you start the application?

Comment: I use npm start.

Comment: If your code can be public, try sharing via code pen or Github. Let me check.

Comment: Here is the link  https://github.com/umakanth-pendyala/complete-react-guide.git

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @UmakanthPendyala, yes. Check updated answer.  Please mark as resolved if it helped.thanks.

Comment: Hey, The issue is solved. But is there any way I can make it look like in the second image I have provided in the question.

Comment: hi, yes. as mentioned by @keysl refer https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are really using Styled Components.

That shows to React Dev tools because you are probably not installing the debugging tools.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components
```

According to the docs it will show as `styled.div` if you don't install this which is pretty much similar to your problem.

More info here: https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging

Comment: I have installed it but, getting the same problem.

Comment: Please check the question, I have added another image.